# git filter-branch ist not removing any files although it displays all the deletions

Tags: git-filter-branch

I have a large repository with all sorts of useful code and want to extract parts of it into a new branch for merging into other projects.

So I thought of the following solution: 1. Create a list of pathnames of the files to keep, 2. Use git filter-branch --prune-empty to remove all the other files and remove commits with touched non of the files of interest.

Everything seemed to work fine, "git filter-branch" even displayed all of the deletions and it looked quite right.

But when it was done, the branch was exactly the same as before!

How can that be?

Here is exactly what I have done:

1. Create a list of all files in the repository as text file "useful":

   $ git log --name-status | sed 's/^[A-Z][[:space:]]{1,}//;t;d' | sort > useful
2. Edit the list and delete all lines containing files which should *not* be kept in the repository, i. e. create a whitelist of files to keep:

   $ "$EDITOR" useful # remove from list what you don't want to keep
3. Export an environment variable for finding the list during execution of "git filter-branch":

   $ export w="$(pwd)"
4. Perform the filter operation:

   $ rm -r -- .git-rewrite; git filter-branch -f --tree-filter 'git ls-files -c | sort | comm -23 -- - "$w"/useful | while IFS= read -r f; do git rm --cached -- "$f"; done' --prune-empty

As explained above, just telling from the output of "git filter-branch" this seems to work fine. But it does not do anything.

Basic explanation of the --tree-filter command expression:

- First "git ls-files -c" is used to create a list of files which has been loaded into the index by filter-branch.
- This list is sorted in the same way as the "useful" list has been.
- Then "comm" is run to compare the list of files returned by "ls-files" with the whitelist in file "useful". The result will be a list of files present in the index but not also in the whitelist.
- The output of the comparison is read by a loop which issues "git rm --cached" commands for all files except those in the whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

I am an **** I: I wanted to use --index-filter, but actually wrote "--tree-filter"!

No wonder nothing did change, because I only deleted files from the index, not from the actual working directory.

After changing this, everything worked perfectly!!!